# Responsive Navbar Not Workingand and Brand gets messy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have figured out my way with css and html as I am not a professional, I only have some basic knowledge.

I used a lot of templates and did some drag and drop here and there.

The problem is my navbar is a lot messy and it doesn't switch to "Hamburger" menu when the bar is full but it goes to the next line instead . It only switches on Middle screens. Here's a Link codepen.io/Guiltyness/pen/vGJLOP

I didn't put a JS file since i don't know which to paste on the pen.
Ty in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

[Your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGJLGM) is not working. You have put all the code over there. You can write code there in the following way:

`<body>
.......
.......
</body>`
No need to write html tags and all.
For CSS and JavaScript files, click on settings and put your links to files there.
[CodePenHelp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMyqv.jpg)

Comment: If the files are already online, you can link to them via your CodePen via the settings menu. This also allows you to add in commonly used resources, like Bootstrap and jQuery.

Comment: I have modified my codepen ,The problem now is obvious , the last two links in my navbar move to the second line as soon as i resize the screen alittle .